# Scala Saddle: Dynamically Creating Vec or Series Objects

Tags: scala, saddle

I am a newbie to Scala, and am very interested in the Saddle Project, as I come from a Python Numpy+Pandas background.

The Documentation shows how to create Vectors and Series in a Static Way like following:

```
val v = Vec(1, 2)                 
val s = Series("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
```

I would like to know (I either did not find it, or don't have sufficient knowledge in Scala to understand on my own) how can I create them dynamically from List or Map objects

How could I do something like this:

For Vectors

```
val myList = List(1,2)
val myVec = Vec(myList)
```

For Series

```
val myMap = Map("a"-> 1, "b"->2)
val mySeries = Series(myMap)
```

**At the moment** it is do the obvious,

For Vector it is creating a Vector with a List as value

```
res48: Vec[List[Int]] = [1 x 1]
List(1, 2)
```

For Series it is creating a Series with the Map object as value

```
res51: Series[Int, Map[String, Int]] = [1 x 1]
0 -> Map(a -> 1, b -> 2)
```

**The Expected Result** is:

For Vector is like if I did:

```
> Vec(1, 2)
res52: Vec[Int] = [2 x 1]
1
2
```

For Series is like if I did:

```
Series("a"-> 1, "b" -> 2)
res53: Series[String, Int] = [2 x 1]
a ->  1
b ->  2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to populate the parameters of the List, you can actually use the :_* operator (semicolon underscore star operator). It actually "splats" the related objet.

To answer to your question, you will have the expected result by doing this for `List`s:

```
val myList = List(1,2)
val myVec = Vec(myList:_*)
```

As for `Maps`, it is a little different from the above as you have to convert the collection to a `Sequence`

```
val myMap = Map("a"->1,"b"->2)
val myVec = Vec(myMap.toSeq:_*)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had thought of this, but couldn't google my way to the answer!